# join streaming and static dataframes does nothing

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

So I'm trying to setup a stream from Kafka, and then add columns from a table to that dataframe based on a matching id in the Kafka message and table.

I've got two separate files, the first one calls a method in streamKafka_ASH to setup the stream and then it prints out the contents.

```
val query = streamKafka_ASH.setupStream(spark, bootstrapservers,zkPath, topics, zkHosts, consumerGroup, batchIntervalSeconds.toInt, autoOffset, checkpointDir)
        .writeStream
        .outputMode("append")
        .format("console")
        .trigger(ProcessingTime(intervalMs = batchIntervalSeconds.toInt * 1000))
        .start()
      query.awaitTermination()
```

And here is the code in streamKafka_ASH.setupStream(...)

```
val marketingTrackingSchema = new StructType()
      .add("id", StringType)
      .add("device", StringType)
      .add("type", StringType)
      .add("mtaid", StringType)
      .add("date", StringType)


val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServers)
  .option("subscribe", topics)
  .option("failOnDataLoss",false)
  .option("group.id", consumerGroup)
  .option("startingOffsets",offsetReset)
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointDir)
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(timestamp AS INT)","CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(key AS STRING)","CAST(value AS STRING)").as[(Int, String, String, String)]

val mt = df.filter($"topic"=== "ASH-MarketingTracking")
// get json from the kafka message and format it as "marketingTrackingSchema"
val df2 = mt.select(col("timestamp").alias("kafka_timestamp"),
  col("topic"),
  $"value",
  from_json(col("value").cast("string"),marketingTrackingSchema).alias("data"))

// get the columns I need from the kafka message
val expandDF2 = df2.select(
  col("kafka_timestamp"),
  col("data.id"),
  col("data.device"),
  col("data.type"),
  col("data.mtaid"),
  col("data.date"),
)


// read in ash-Config from external hive table
val testExtHiveDF = spark.read.table("hbase_external.ash_config")

// get values I need from external hive table 
val mtConfigDF = testExtHiveDF.selectExpr(
  "trackingid as mtaid",
  "relationshiptype",
  "channel",
  "subchannel"
)


expandDF2.join(mtConfigDF, "mtaid")
expandDF2.createOrReplaceTempView("test")

// this line is just to test if join worked, would normally return entire joined dataframe
val joinedDF2 = spark.sql("select channel from test")
```

I went through the debugger and after the join, the dataframes are the same and nothing changed. An error occurs at the joinedDF2 line:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`channel`' given input columns: [type, device, id, date,  kafka_timestamp, mtaid]; line 1 pos 7;
```

Maybe I'm doing the join wrong or reading in the data wrong? I've been working on this for a while, and it seems simple, but I'm just not sure what to do.

---

**Update:**
So I tried doing the join with `spark.sql` and got an error, here is my code for the SQL join, which happens at the same place as the other join

```
mtConfigDF.createOrReplaceTempView("mtconfigDF")
expandDF2.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
val joinedDF2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM test INNER JOIN mtconfigDF ON test.mtaid = mtconfigDF.mtaid")

// then return joinedDF2
joinedDF2
```

If I return expandDF2 instead of joinedDF2, then it'll run fine and just print out the stuff in expandDF2. But I need to join the two dataframes and when I return joinedDF2, I get this:

```
18/07/27 15:47:33 ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 8eaf1def-8fba-41db-a91d-dcda94c90721, runId = fa6f4cf8-97c4-4e54-983a-46ea703964eb] terminated with error
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for CatalogRelation `hbase_external`.`ash_config`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe, [trackingid#274, relationshiptype#275, channel#276, subchannel#277]

at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(StreamExecution.scala:651)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(StreamExecution.scala:643)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:643)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:290)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: assertion failed: No plan for CatalogRelation `hbase_external`.`ash_config`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe, [trackingid#274, relationshiptype#275, channel#276, subchannel#277]

=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = 8eaf1def-8fba-41db-a91d-dcda94c90721, runId = fa6f4cf8-97c4-4e54-983a-46ea703964eb]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaSource[Subscribe[ASH-MarketingTracking, ASH-MarketingTrackingConfig]]: {"ASH-MarketingTracking":{"2":2275,"1":2260,"0":2269},"ASH-MarketingTrackingConfig":{"2":564,"1":528,"0":580}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
 Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
Project [kafka_timestamp#72, id#209, device#210, type#211, mtaid#212, date#213, mtaid#315, relationshiptype#275, channel#276, subchannel#277]
+- Join Inner, (mtaid#212 = mtaid#315)
   :- SubqueryAlias test
   :  +- Project [kafka_timestamp#72, data#73.id AS id#209, data#73.device AS device#210, data#73.type AS type#211, data#73.mtaid AS mtaid#212, data#73.date AS date#213,]
   :     +- Project [timestamp#56 AS kafka_timestamp#72, topic#57, value#59, jsontostructs(StructField(id,StringType,true), StructField(device,StringType,true), StructField(type,StringType,true), StructField(mtaid,StringType,true), StructField(date,StringType,true), cast(value#59 as string), Some(America/New_York)) AS data#73]
   :        +- Filter (topic#57 = ASH-MarketingTracking)
   :           +- Project [cast(timestamp#46 as int) AS timestamp#56, cast(topic#43 as string) AS topic#57, cast(key#41 as string) AS key#58, cast(value#42 as string) AS value#59]
   :              +- StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaSource[Subscribe[ASH-MarketingTracking, ASH-MarketingTrackingConfig]], [key#41, value#42, topic#43, partition#44, offset#45L, timestamp#46, timestampType#47]
   +- SubqueryAlias mtconfigdf
       +- Project [marketingtrackingassociationid#274 AS mtaid#315, relationshiptype#275, channel#276, subchannel#277]
       +- SubqueryAlias ash_marketing_tracking_config
              +- CatalogRelation `hbase_external`.`ash_config`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe, [marketingtrackingassociationid#274,  relationshiptype#275, channel#276, subchannel#277]

at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:343)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for CatalogRelation `hbase_external`.`ash_config`, org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe, [marketingtrackingassociationid#274,  relationshiptype#275, channel#276, subchannel#277]

at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$foldLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.foldLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:157)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foldLeft(Iterator.scala:1336)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:74)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner$$anonfun$2.apply(QueryPlanner.scala:66)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.planning.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(StreamExecution.scala:651)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(StreamExecution.scala:643)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatch(StreamExecution.scala:643)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(StreamExecution.scala:306)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:279)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches$1.apply$mcZ$sp(StreamExecution.scala:294)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:56)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:290)
... 1 more
```